# anchors.baseline in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

There is some Defination confused me... I found a Text's anchors.baseline is different from Rectangle's.. Why ?  what is the defination of baseline ?  Thank you ...

```
Item {
    width: 400; height: 200

    Rectangle {
        y:20
        id: rectangle
        width: 80; height: 80
        color: "red"
    }

    Text {
        text: "Hello World!"
        anchors.baseline: rectangle.baseline
        anchors.left: rectangle.right
    }
}
```

[image]
**Rectangle's baseline is top, and Text's baseline is bottom?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The baseline corresponds to the imaginary line on which text would sit. For items with no text it is the same as top.

Comment: yeah! thanks for helping... And there is another question, can you help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443053/some-exercise-about-qml  would you help me ? thank you..